# Are there any open source mapping / GIS frameworks written in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, open-source, mapping, gis

I've been looking for an open source mapping / GIS framework along the lines of [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/) but written in Silverlight. Unfortunately I have not been able to find one.

Preferably it would be able to consume services (e.g., maps, tiles, geocoding services) from the major map / GIS providers, including (in order of preference):

- [MapServer](http://mapserver.org/)
- [Google Maps](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/)
- [Virtual Earth](http://dev.live.com/Virtualearth/sdk/)
- [ArcGIS Server](http://resources.esri.com/arcgisserver/)

Are there any open source GIS frameworks written in Silverlight with similar functionality to [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/) or the [ArcGIS Server Flex ADF](http://resources.esri.com/arcgisserver/apis/flex/)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's [DeepEarth](http://www.codeplex.com/deepearth). You can find the demo site [here](http://deepearth.soulsolutions.com.au/).

Comment: Thanks for the link. At first glance this looks promising, I'll be sure to take a closer look.

Answer (score 1):

What about the [ESRI Silverlight Control](http://weblogs.asp.net/albertpascual/archive/2008/08/14/esri-silverlight-control-up-on-the-code-gallery.aspx)?

Comment: I'm specifically looking for open source solutions. My understanding is that you cannot use the ESRI Web frameworks without a license of ArcGIS Server which is around $30K for a minimal system.

Answer (score 0):

[azukiMap](http://azukimap.codeplex.com/) can be the one. It seems not stable, but the developer updates often. I think it will be the good solution.